# Is there a way to pass a Handlebars partial (with variables) into another helper?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

So there is a template file that is generating a few different layouts for a component in my webpage with different variables dictating sizes and whatnot. So in order to reduce the number of files in the project, I'm trying to reuse the template files for code snippets instead of having dedicated files for them. Through sub expressions, I've had the idea of doing something like this:

```
{{ escape (template var1=var1 var2=var2 var3=var3) }}
```

where `escape` is a helper that takes a string and escapes it (funnily enough), and:

```
(template var1=var1 var2=var2 var3=var3)
```

is supposed to have the same effect as `{{> template var1=var1 var2=var2 var3=var3 }}`, returning complete markup presumably as a string.

The helper doesn't seem to be receiving any string since running `typeof` on the parameter is returning `undefined`. I had assumed since `{{> template var1=var1 var2=var2 var3=var3 }}` is being used higher up in the file, that was registering it for use within the rest of the file, but now I'm thinking that's not how Handlebars does its thing.

Is it possible to retrieve the partial like this or does it need to use the `{{>` syntax (which doesn't work)?

Comment: Why not change `template` from a partial to a block helper, as that is how you want to use it?

Comment: Yeah, compiling a partial programmatically wasn't something I was familiar with when I submitted this question. I'm now trying to use that approach rather than what I was attempting above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the time I asked this question, I was a bit confused with how a context was applied to a partial programmatically. Now that I've done a bit more research (I did try before asking but got nowhere), I now know that `Handlebars.compile(partial)` will return an object for the given partial and allow a context to be given through `partial(context)` which should be returned.

---

**Sample Code**

```
function escape(partial) {
    let compiledPartial = Handlebars.compile(partial);

    let context = { greeting: "Hello World!" };

    return compiledPartial(context);
}
```